# Shopify / Liquid Operators - Contains Only

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am looking for a liquid operator for if a string contains only (i.e. an **exact** match of) the string specified.

For instance, supposing I have two tags for a product, 'Black' and 'Black and White' and I only want to trigger an event only for 'Black', how would I go about this? The below liquid would trigger both and thus output the message twice.

```
{% if tag contains 'Black' %} Hi {% endif %}
```

I have tried e.g.

```
{% if tag = 'Black' %} Hi {% endif %}
```

But this gives an error and does not seem to be allowed. Is there instead an operator for an exact match for a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `contains` operator against arrays it does perform an exact match.

For example, if your product has only `Black and White` tag the `product.tags contains "Black"` won't return `true`, because `product.tags` is an array. It will only return `true` if the product has the `Black` tag.

It looks like you used it within the loop against each tag individually where `tag` is a string. In this case `contains` returns `true` when a part of a string the matches the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using `==` rather than `=` as an operator works.

Comment: I ended up here because I found that this is not the case. `==` does not lead to truthy but falsy for me. With the `contains` operator, it works. 

But just like the previous speaker I am unsure as I want also an exact match.

Does anyone know why the `==` operator as a string operator is not working?